# Why so many users in my own linux pc?

Tags: linux, users

I'm just find out that there are over 40+ users in my pc which running Linux OS. Do they even have password? I'm the only one users here. What is the point of having so many user in my own linux pc? I'm using linux almost a month right now.

Comment: To avoid misunderstandings, please [edit] and tell us *how* you found out. There's a huge difference between "my `/etc/passwd` contains 44 entries (lines)" and "on my graphical login screen there are suddenly 44 names to choose from".

Comment: The seventh field in `/etc/passwd` is the default login shell for that user. 37 of mine use a "shell" called `/usr/sbin/nologin`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's normal.

Programs running under the same user account have an implicit trust relationship, for example if one program is a debugger, it may stop the other program, modify it in-place and let it continue.

For security reasons, programs that should not be able to do that are running as different users.

The same mechanism is also used on Android to isolate apps from each other.